# Prevent inherited member from accessing protected member

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, polymorphism

Is there a way in C# to prevent a derived class from inheriting a protected property?

```
class Base
{
   protected int A { get; set; }
}

class DerivedA : Base
{
}

class DerivedB : DerivedA
{
}
```

What I want is for DerivedA to be able to access property A, however DerivedB should not. So is there a way to limit the inheritance of a property in the middle of the inheritance hierarcy?

Comment: This is not possible. Why are you trying to do that? Maybe `private protected` can help you?

Comment: Possibly not related, but if you don't want a class to be derived from, you can apply the `sealed` modifier.

Comment: Nope. Can't be done. Once something is in the base class, it gets passed down to all inheritors - even if that something is declared private, by the way. (private means the member is not accessible in any other class, but it still gets inherited).

Comment: @ZoharPeled I just don't want it to be accessable, just as if it was private.

Comment: Depending on your context, there might be some workarounds (i.e. when different assemblies are involved, or by using extension methods). Please specify why you would need this.

Comment: Why is the member protected when you don´t want it to appear in the inheritance-chain? MAybe you should move that member to `DerivedA`, as it doesn´t seem to belong into all classes deriving from `Base`.

Comment: @Lorago still can't do it. You can't change the base class members access modifier in the derived class. (if that was possible, it would conflict with LSP).

Comment: @PMF I'm essentially creating an assignment game for school, where people get to create AI for a game. So I'm creating the game that students will code AI for. However I need to pass the Game class to my objects as they need to instantiate objects into the game. However to prevent cheating students should not have access to the Game property from the Object class as they would be able to create objects among other things.

Comment: But obviously there is some object that should be able to access the game-object. So what makes this one different from those objects that derive from your base-class and should *not* be able to do this?

Comment: @Lorago Then `private protected` is what your need. It makes your member protected when accessed from inside the same assembly, but private for anything outside of it. In short, you'll see your members as protected, but when your students reference your assembly, they'll see them as private

Comment: Maybe have a look at "Composition over Inheritance" ?

Comment: It seems you have an XY-problem, that is you think making a member protected is the solution of your actual problem. Maybe you could provide some more meaningful code that the current one, as it´s hard to understand what exactly you´re doing.

Comment: @KevinGosse it's worth mentioning that the `private protected` is only avaiable since C# version 7.2. You should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I don't have time right now, I need to run. Feel free to post it :)

Comment: Lorago, you should add your above comment to the question. It sheds some light on your approach. I second @HimBromBeere regarding the x-y-Problem. From my view, I think you should use an Interface and provide "game-services" via composition.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Even though there is a clear solution to OPs *posted* question (see Kevin Gosse´s comment), it´s probably not the answer to the *underlying* problem.

Comment: @Fildor now that I read the question again it seems to me that it's not inheritance at all. It's like both Base and DerivedA classes have a private property A.

Comment: @roozbehS I am not able to follow you. OP is looking for a solution to have a protected member of a base class not being visible to descendants deeper in the inheritance tree than 1 step (2nd and further down). As far as I read the question, that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is some valuable information in the comments, so I thought I'd better recap it so it will not get lost.

[Kevin Gosse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869621/kevin-gosse) suggested to use the [`private protected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected) access modifier.

> The `private protected` keyword combination is a member access modifier. A private protected member is accessible by types derived from the containing class, but only within its containing assembly.

Please note that this access modifier is only available in c# 7.2 or higher.

While I agree with Kevin this might be a direct answer to your question, [HimBromBeere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528063/himbrombeere) suggested that this question is, in fact, an [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - meaning you are asking how to implement a solution you are having problems with, instead of asking how to solve the underlying problem.
I also agree with him as well.

[Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor) suggested using [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) - which is a very good point. using inheritance only for code reuse is a mistake. Remember that a derived class is a specific type of the base class type - for instance, a dog can derive from animal because a dog is a specific type of animal, but an airplane can't derive from a car just because they both have engines.

To get an answer to the actual underlying problem, I suggest you edit your question to include that problem, not only the current solution you are trying to implement, or perhaps ask a brand new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should make it sealed:

```
class Base
{
   protected int A { get; set; }
}

class DerivedA : Base
{
   protected sealed override int A { get => base.A; set => base.A = value; }
}

class DerivedB : DerivedA
{
   // Attempting to override A causes compiler error.
}
```

read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed

Comment: I think you misunderstood. OP wants DerivedB to not be able to access A at all. Not only not able to override it.

Comment: If you are overriding it in `DerivedA`, it must be virtual in `Base`... Also, this still doesn't answer the original question - `A` will still be accessible to `DerivedB`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want a class to not inheriting a protected property of its base class?
You should redesign your class model:

```
    class Base
    {            
    }

    class BaseA : Base
    {
        protected int A { get; set; }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
    }

    class DerivedA : BaseA
    {
    }
```

Comment: I think you are on to something. Maybe not exactly your example, but basically "Composition over Inheritance".